# FileInputStream and FileOutputStream in Java

Tags: java

I was studying this topic and one thing i couldn't get it that when we want to create or to access a file and write something in it why we use FileOutputStream. We want to write something in a file input is for writing why we are not using FileInputStream?

Answer (score 1):

FileOutputStream is used to write the file.

and FileInputStream is used to read the file.

I think you are confused with "out" and "in" words.

Just take it like, "out" means I am sending something outside and this something would be written in a file.

same as, "in" word from FileInputStream means we are taking something from a file  or you can say we reading something from a file.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: ya i was confused with "out" and "in".......now its clear.....Thankx Sonu Gupta....

Answer (score 0):

Consider this from your program's perspective - *If your program wants to write something as output, use `FileOutputStream`. If your program wants some input from a file, use `FileInputStream`*.

Comment: @Saad - `Output` --> write . `input` --> read. So the stream names are different